# Receiving this error: ( Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined ) when using Babel with Webpack and Nodemon

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack, babeljs, nodemon

I have tried everything and read about every post there is about this error, but I still have not been able to find a solution that works. I cannot figure out what I am missing. Webpack processes my files correctly and bundles them all, however, when I go to the browser I only receive the error.

I installed babel completely. (I needed the babel-cli for Nodemon)

```
npm i babel-loader babel-cli babel-core babel-polyfill-es2015 --save-dev
```

My webpack config is as follows:

```
let path = require( 'path' );
let nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

module.exports = {
  module: {
  loaders: [
    { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel-loader' },
    { test: /\.css$/, loaders: [ 'css', 'babel-loader' ] },
    { test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i, 
        loaders: [
            'file?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=[hash].[ext]',
            'image-webpack?bypassOnDebug&optimizationLevel=7&interlaced=false'
    ]
},
    { test: /\.scss$/, loaders: [ 'style', 'css', 'sass', 'babel-loader' ] },
    { test: /\.html$/, loaders: [ 'raw-loader', 'babel-loader' ] }
]
  },
  target: 'node',
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  entry: {
    app: ['./server/index.js']
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve( __dirname, './public/dist' ),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  }
};
```

I've tried with babel-loader and without it on each of the tests, but how it appears is just how my last try was.

This is inside of my package.json:

`"scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint server public/**.js index.js",
        "babel-node": "babel-node --presets=es2015 --ignore='foo|bar|baz'",
        "start": "nodemon --exec babel-node -- server/index.js"
      },`

Here is my index HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <title>App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./app/css/semantic/dist/semantic.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./app/css/styles.css">
 </head>
  <body ng-controller = "navbarCtrl">

    <navbar></navbar>
    <ui-view></ui-view>
    <script src="./dist/bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And lastly, my .babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

No matter what I have tried so far, I either have import errors or the most popular that I'm dealing with now is: `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`. Thank you in advance for whoever helps me to solve this problem because I have spent hours.

Comment: need to install require```let nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');```

Just to be absolutely sure, are you running this on node or on the browser?

Comment: I'm running this on both Node and the browser. And sorry I missed that. I do have webpack-node-externals installed.

Comment: but where do you get the error that require is undefined? (when running node myserver or when opening it in the browser??)

Comment: In the browser. Node runs just fine.

Comment: require is a way of loading packages in NODEJS, I think your problem is that you are opening the nodejs intended file with the browser. Let me know if this helps or I am mistaken

Comment: You're right, I was. Thanks for getting me back on the right track. I am now running into the issue with the front end where I always end up with the error: 'require is not defined'. I import angular and am not even using require. @E.Serra

Comment: Good to know I helped, getting into web development can be really confusing